# How to open a multi-frame TIFF imageformat image in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, tiff, system.drawing

```
Image.FromFile(@"path\filename.tif")
```

or

```
Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
```

both produce image objects with only one frame even though the source is a multi-frame TIFF file. **How do you load an image file that retains these frames?** The tiffs are saved using the Image.SaveAdd methods frame by frame. They work in other viewers but .NET Image methods will not load these frames, only the first.

**Does this mean that there is no way to return a multi-frame TIFF from a method where I am passing in a collection of bitmaps to be used as frames?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's what I use:

```
private List<Image> GetAllPages(string file)
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(file);
    int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
    {
        // save each frame to a bytestream
        bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx);
        MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

        // and then create a new Image from it
        images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream));
    }
    return images;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to return a multi-frame TIFF from a method where I am passing in a collection of bitmaps to be used as frames?

Comment: Pretty much yes - you have to remember that in a multiframe TIFF each frame can have its own set of encoding options (compression, color, quality). Bitmaps on the other hand are much simpler animals.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to handle the multi-frame tiff by using the below method.

```
Image multiImage = Image.FromFile(sourceFile);

multiImage.Save(destinationFile, tiff, prams);

int pageCount = multiImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

for (int page = 1; page < pageCount; page++ )
{
    multiImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page,page);
    multiImage.SaveAdd(dupImage,prams);
}

multiImage.SaveAdd(newPage, prams);
multiImage.Dispose();
```

I have not tried the solution in .net 2.0 but MSDN shows the class members to exist.  It did fix my problem in .net 4.5.2.

Comment: What is dupImage?

Answer (score -1):

bitmap.Dispose();

After For loop you need to Dispose bitmap. Otherwise you get error "file using other process" when try to use same file in other process.