# Cropping a Image Using C#

Tags: c#, image, crop, tiff

I want to crop a tiff image. The tiff image which contains certain fields. i want to crop a particular area in the tiff image which the image size varies but i want to crop the particular area.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: I'm confused by "i want to crop a particular area ... but i want to crop the particular area." Can you clarify?

Comment: Eg: In that image there will be field Called "Name" . I want to crop that field only . How will we do this.?

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

[How to open a multi-frame TIFF imageformat image in .NET 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401561/how-to-open-a-multi-frame-tiff-imageformat-image-in-net-2-0)

Now without any problems you should do this :)

How to crop image itself you can find here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/15/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-simple-image-manipulations-using-webimage-helper.aspx

Just download WebImage helper class read about it (how to do) and use it.

Comment: does that answer involve cropping?

Comment: I look that code, but i need to crop a tiff image but that code not seems like that.. so please