# Saving a multi frame TIFF

Tags: c#, tiff

I load a multiframe TIFF from a Stream in my C# application, and then save it using the Image.Save method. However, this only saves the TIFF with the first frame - how can I get it to save a multiframe tiff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a multi-frame TIFF imageformat image in .NET 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401561/how-to-open-a-multi-frame-tiff-imageformat-image-in-net-2-0)

Comment: The link you gave is for Loading not saving...

Comment: The link also includes the answer, though it's actually in the question: "The tiffs are saved using the Image.SaveAdd methods frame by frame".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't provide any detailed information... just some general tips:

Multi-Frame TIFF are very complex files - for example every frame can have a different encoding... a single `Bitmap`/`Image` can't hold all frames with all relevant information (like encoding and similar) of such a file, only one at a time.

For loading you need to set parameter which tells the class which frame to load, otherwise it just loads the first... for some code see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401561/how-to-open-a-multi-frame-tiff-imageformat-image-in-net-2-0).

Similar problems arise when saving multi-frame TIFFs - here you need to work with [`EncoderParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameters.aspx) and use [`SaveAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.saveadd.aspx) etc. - for some working code see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388/convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0).

Answer (score 0):

Since the link to code provided by @Yahia is broken I have decided to post the code I ended up using.

In my case, the multi-frame TIFF already exists and all I need to do is to load the image, rotate by EXIF (if necessary) and save. I won't post the EXIF rotation code here, since it does not relate to this question.

```
using (Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourceStream))
{
  using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
  {
    int pages = img.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
    if (pages == 1)
    {
      img.Save(fileStream, img.RawFormat); // if there is just one page, just save the file
    }
    else
    {
      var encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(x => x.MimeType == fileInfo.MediaType);
      var encoderParams = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);

      encoderParams.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, Convert.ToInt32(System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.MultiFrame));
      img.Save(fileStream, encoder, encoderParams); // save the first image with MultiFrame parameter

      for (int f = 1; f < pages; f++)
      {
        img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, f); // select active page (System.Drawing.Image.FromStream loads the first one by default)

        encoderParams.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, Convert.ToInt32(System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage));
        img.SaveAdd(img, encoderParams); // save add with FrameDimensionPage parameter
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- *sourceStream* is a System.IO.MemoryStream which holds the byte array of the file content
- *filePath* is absolute path to cache directory (something like 'C:/Cache/multiframe.tiff')
- *fileInfo* is a model holding the actual byte array, fileName, mediaType and other data